# how to stop playing Spotify on my Galaxy Tab

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, spotify

I can start and play Spotify on my Galaxy Tab 7 but if i have enough, how do i stop playing without total log-out or without using the pause. I want to STOP and close it. I have Premium

Comment: Push the bottom left (all open apps) and use the X close on the Spotify display.

Comment: The bottom left of what?  Do you mean long-press the Menu button?

Answer (score 3):

In Android it's not necessary to stop and close apps manually. Android manages the state of applications in the background, when an app is not actively performing a task. If the device needs memory for a new application, Android closes the least active app still in the background to make room for it. As a result if you open an application that was still in the background, it can now open much faster. In the case of Spotify, it remains paused in the background until you open it again, or the device needs memory for another application.

More information here: http://lifehacker.com/5650894/android-task-killers-explained-what-they-do-and-why-you-shouldnt-use-them